# Assign a User to an Enterprise Application in Azure AD through Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Through the PHP Graph SDK, I'm attempting to pragmatically assign a user to an Enterprise Application. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: users/{user-id}...
```

Here is my function

```
 public function assignUserToApp($user,$app)
{
$token = $this->getToken();
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($token)
->setApiVersion('beta');

$newMemberRef = '/users/'.$user->getId().'/appRoleAssignments';
$response = $graph->createRequest('PATCH', $newMemberRef)
        ->attachBody([
            "principalId" => $user->getId(),
            "principalType" => "User",
            "resourceId" => $app,
            "creationTimestamp" => gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z")])
        ->execute();
}
```

I will greatly appreciate any form of  help.

Answer (score -1):

The prototype for [updating `/appRoleAssignments`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/approleassignment_update) is:

```
PATCH /users/{userId}/appRoleAssignments/{appRoleId}
```

You're missing the `/{appRoleId}` from your request.

Comment: Where do I get the appRoleId? That has been my challenge.

Comment: You get it from the `appRoles` collection of the [`application` resource](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/application).

Comment: I managed to get AppRoleId using graph explorer but still getting same error

Comment: Can you provide a PCAP or Fiddler trace showing the actual HTTP call going over the wire?